# How to calculate a column value based on the same column in pandas?(Not a duplicate question, did my research)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
dict1 = {'name':['name1','name1','name1','name1','name2','name2','name2'],
         'Totalqty':[30000,30000,30000,30000,18000,18000,18000],
         'fillqty':[5000,15000,5000,5000,3000,6000,9000],
         'date':['2021-01-20','2021-01-22','2021-01-21','2021-01-23','2021-01-22','2021-01-21','2021-01-23']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)


   Totalqty        date  fillqty   name
0     30000  2021-01-20     5000  name1
1     30000  2021-01-22    15000  name1
2     30000  2021-01-21     5000  name1
3     30000  2021-01-23     5000  name1
4     18000  2021-01-22     3000  name2
5     18000  2021-01-21     6000  name2
6     18000  2021-01-23     9000  name2
```

Now I want to introduce a new column 'remaining' which :

1. Calculates the remaining qty which is Totalqty minus the fillqty for the first day
2. Then we subtract the 1st day remaining qty from the 2nd day fillqty to get the 2nd day remaining qty and so on.

P.S All the calculations are done according to the name and this has to be sorted day wise:

So the result would look like this:

```
   Totalqty        date  fillqty   name   remaining
0     30000  2021-01-20     5000  name1       25000
1     30000  2021-01-21     5000  name1       20000
2     30000  2021-01-22    15000  name1       50000
3     30000  2021-01-23     5000  name1           0
4     18000  2021-01-21     6000  name2       12000
5     18000  2021-01-22     3000  name2        9000
6     18000  2021-01-23     9000  name2           0
```

Till now I have used the transform('max') function to get the value for Totalqty and subtracted it from the fill qty for the first day.

```
 df['remaining'] = df.groupby('name')['Totalqty'].transform('max') - df['fillqty']
```

But this subtracts all the rows from the Totalqty which I dont want as I have explained above. Not sure how to move forward.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: df['remaining'] = df[‘Totalqty’].sub(df.groupby('name')['fillqty’].cumsum())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=["name", "date"])

df["remaining"] = df["Totalqty"] - df.groupby("name")["fillqty"].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Totalqty        date  fillqty   name  remaining
0     30000  2021-01-20     5000  name1      25000
2     30000  2021-01-21     5000  name1      20000
1     30000  2021-01-22    15000  name1       5000
3     30000  2021-01-23     5000  name1          0
5     18000  2021-01-21     6000  name2      12000
4     18000  2021-01-22     3000  name2       9000
6     18000  2021-01-23     9000  name2          0
```